# React-Native, Google Photos API Image Upload

Tags: react-native, base64, blob, google-photos, octetstring

**react-native + expo**

TL;DR: Does anyone have a working example of react-native/expo working with an in app camera and uploading an image to the 'new' [google api](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/overview)?

1. Authenticate user (working)
2. [Make Album](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/create-albums) (working)
3. [Make Album Shareable](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/share-media) (working)
4. Take Photo (working)
5. [Get UploadToken](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media#upload-process) (Seems like it is working)
6. [Upload Photo](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/upload-media#uploading-bytes) (not working)

Why I think (5) seems like it is working, because the getUploadToken function returns successfully, response 200, and provides a key.

Why I think it might be a dumb service on the other end of (5), I can post just about anything to it and it will return successfully.

My hunch is that there is something wrong with the way I am uploading the image to the /uploads endpoint.

IE: not in the correct format.

this.state.image == {'base64':'base64string','uri':'file://...',...}

I do see an album is being created within my google photos, and I can see that it is set to shareable, with no privileges (users can not comment, or add their own photos)

**2 MAKE ALBUM**

```
makeAlbum = () => {
    //MAKE ALBUM
    fetch('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+this.state.accessToken
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "album": {"title": this.state.albumTemp}
      }),
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        [
          this.shareAlbum(response),
          console.log('make: ',response)
        ]
    });
  }
}
```

**3 MAKE ALBUM SHAREABLE**

```
shareAlbum = (response) =>{
    this.setState({albumId:response.id})
    //MAKE ALBUM SHAREABLE
    fetch('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/albums/'+this.state.albumId+':share',{
      method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer '+this.state.accessToken
        }
    }).then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response)=>{
        [
          this.setState({shareable:response.shareInfo.shareableUrl}),
          console.log('share1: ',this.state.shareable),
          console.log('share2: ',response),
        ]
    });
  }
```

**4 CAPTURE PHOTO**

```
capturePhoto = async () => {
    let image = await this._camera.takePictureAsync({
      base64: true,
      quality: .5,
      width: 1920,
      fixOrientation: true
    })
    this.setState({ image: image, capturing: false })
    // delay the capture a few seconds to make sure it's rendered
    setTimeout(async () => {
      let result = await takeSnapshotAsync(this._previewRef, {
        format: 'png',
        result: 'tmpfile',
        quality: 1
      });
      //upload the photo to google photos album
      this.getUploadToken(image)
    }, 1000)
  }
```

**5 GET UPLOAD TOKEN**

```
getUploadToken = (image) => {
    let name = this.state.image.uri.split('/')
    name=name[name.length-1]
    fetch('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/uploads', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+this.state.accessToken,
        'X-Goog-Upload-File-Name': name,
        'X-Goog-Upload-Protocol': 'raw'
      },
      body:image,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('setup upload: ',response)
      this.uploadPhoto(response._bodyText); 
    })
  }
```

**6 UPLOAD PHOTO**

```
uploadPhoto = (token) => {
fetch('https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems:batchCreate', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer '+this.state.accessToken,
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({
        "albumId": this.state.albumId,
        "newMediaItems": [
          {
            "description": "Event Photo",
            "simpleMediaItem": {
              "uploadToken": token
            }
          }
        ]
      })
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('actual upload: ',response)
      this.setState({ ready: true, image: null })
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5 GET UPLOAD TOKEN API works find, just the description is wrong on Google Documentation. Instead of Base64 the input is in form of Binary. I have tried in Postman(below screenshot):

Get Upload Token API:
[Get Upload Token API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axC7c.png)

Upload Media:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vDnF.png)

Comment: Good find. I ended up writing gross work-around, I will reimplement with this. Thanks.

Comment: @mbunch Glad it help :)

Comment: @PramodMali how do I upload the binary ?, I've the URI of the media

Comment: @cpt.Sparrow Please refer the code below for same:

https://github.com/malipramod/google-photos-migration-api-nodejs/blob/master/routes/controllers/migrate-controller.js#L67

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying the same thing in a Node Express app.
Don't forget that you need to upload the image in binary, and not in base64.
It also looks like you don't pass a parameter in step 4 to the function getUploadToken().

My app also returns the `"message": "NOT_IMAGE: There was an error while trying to create this media item."`.

In my node app i convert the Buffer to a binary with

`const fileBinary = file.data.toString('binary')`

Comment: Right, that seems to be the sticking point in react-native, is obtaining the image as binary. The only way I know to do it is to use react-native-fetch-blob, but to use that you/I need to detach the expo project (which I was hoping to avoid) 
-- Good catch on the uploadToken.

Answer (score 1):

Step 5 certainly does not work... You are not sending an image at all!

In step 4 you call this:

```
this.getUploadToken()
```

While in step 5

```
getUploadToken = (image) => {
```

image is then used as body.

Did you check your network tab while testing? It looks like you would be receiving a 400 error.

Comment: You are correct, though the issue still persists once I have passed the image.
It has to do with react-native image binaries. Currently, I'm looking into react-native-fetch-blob. Thanks.